# How to fill a rounded rectangle with different color segments by area in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and I tried looking for examples online and the documentations but couldn't find something. I want something like this:

[image]

I tried it using a QLinearGradient but it isn't quite what I want. I want solid colors.
Here's what I've tried:

```
void drawBackground ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const {
    QLinearGradient linearGrad(QPointF(option.rect.x(), 0), QPointF(option.rect.x() + option.rect.width(), 0));

    int total = index.data(StatisticsModel::TotalCount).toInt();
    linearGrad.setColorAt(0.0, QColor(255, 255, 255, 0));

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 7; i >= 1; i--) {
        int count = index.data(StatisticsModel::Grade0 + i).toInt();

        if (count) {
            sum += count;
            linearGrad.setColorAt(1.0-((double)(total-sum))/total, Prefs::gradeColor(i));

        }
    }


    QRect rect(option.rect);
    rect.adjust(1, 1, -1, -1);

    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRoundedRect( rect, 2.0, 2.0 );
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(linearGrad));
    painter->drawPath(path);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know the ratio of each segment and want solid colours why not use `QPainter::drawRect` to draw each segment separately?

Comment: It could still be done with a gradient: You could put two points at each color change, with only a tiny distance between them. The first point would be the left color and the second point would be the right color. So each color span would have two points of the same color to interpolate between, which would create a solid color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the best way to color rounded rectangle like this I guess would be to create `QPainterPath` for it then construct normal rectangles which should be of specified color intersect them with initial rounded rectangle `QPainterPath` using function `QPainterPath::intersected` and draw them, selecting corresponding solid color brush and using function `drawPath`